# swiper slider reinitialize repopulate older images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [Swiper slider](http://idangero.us/swiper/) for image sliding.

HTML structure.

```
<div class="slider">
    <li><img src="image10"><l1>
    <li><img src="image11"><l1>
    <li><img src="image12"><l1>
    <li><img src="image13"><l1>
    <li class="last-slide"><l1>
</div>
```

I need to dynamically reload 'slider' class div with new images on click of other color swatches/images.

before adding new images, first need to clean older ones.

```
$('.slider').childer().detach();

newImages = 'new images from api call or cache';

$('slider').append(newImages);
```

this suppose to load like this

```
<div class="slider">
    <li><img src="image20"><l1>
    <li><img src="image21"><l1>
    <li><img src="image22"><l1>
    <li><img src="image23"><l1>
    <li class="last-slide"><l1>
</div>
```

but what exactly happening is, it loads previous images as well like this .

```
<div class="slider">
    <li><img src="image20"><l1>
    <li><img src="image21"><l1>
    <li><img src="image22"><l1>
    <li><img src="image23"><l1>
    <li class="last-slide"><l1>
    <li><img src="image10"><l1>
    <li><img src="image11"><l1>
    <li><img src="image12"><l1>
    <li><img src="image13"><l1>
    <li class="last-slide"><l1>
</div>
```

As i have debugged the code it works fine as in DOM it loads new images until i call

```
slider.reIntialize() / slider.update()
```

(tried both separately) to re initialize slider as if i don't slider get stuck;

even i have used

```
$('.slider li.last-slide').nextAll().remove();
```

to remove any extra slides added and then reIntialize / update slider.

Please ignore any syntax error in code above, I have rewritten the same to explain the logic. original code its self has no errors but adds previous slides every time when I loads new images.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: here it is working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/bogKwBfl8Uc9jZPikI1M?p=preview

Comment: instead of `append()` try `htm()` and see

Comment: @PunithJain thanks, Actually i got my issue. I was detaching ".swiper-container" which was the main container. if i detach $('.swiper-wrapper').children().detach(); , It works fine.